# SQL Server stored procedure cannot be modified according to "wrong" comment part

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing this; I could not found a related solution with this heading and decided to write the solution also here.

Sometime when we define a new stored procedure on SQL Server, it cannot be modified by right click method according to some "Syntax Error" part in the code

> Syntax Error in TextHeader of stored procedure 'your_procedure'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

And so, you need to get the code of the procedure by `sp_helptext` method.

In short, there must be a `/* */` comment division part in another `/* */` comment part. (This was my situation)

Please write here if you know other possibilities about the

> Syntax Error in TextHeader of stored procedure ...

error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a `/* */` comment division part(s) in another `/* */` comment part(s). Changing `/ * * /` seperated string in the main comment part(s).